# Как убрать запятую между данными обернутыми в тег li из массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребята, всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста с выводом.

Ситуация такая, нужно сделать вывод загруженных файлов в теге `li`, то есть каждый загруженный файл выводиться в теге `li`, сейчас они выводятся через запятую.

Буду благодарен за подсказку!

```js
$("#files").change(function(){ // Выполняем функцию после выбора файлов
        
  var name_file = []; // Создаем массив

  for(var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) { // Запускаем цикл и перебираем все файлы

    name_file.push($(this).get(0).files[i].name); // Добавляем имена файлов в массив

  } 

  $("#file-name").text(name_file.split(", ")); // Выводим список имен в id="file-name", разделенных запятой

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files">
<ul id="file-name"></ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).get(0)` тоже самое что и `this`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что бы избавиться от запятой соедините элементы массива воспользовавшись методом [join("")](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
// $("#files").on("change", function() {
// const name_file = []
const name_file = ["Имя1", "Имя2", "Имя3"] // для примера
// for (let i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
//   name_file.push($(this).get(0).files[i].name)
// }
const elements = name_file.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`)
$("#file-name").html(elements.join(""))
// })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files">
<ul id="file-name"></ul>
```

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы каждое имя файла выводилось в отдельном теге li?

Comment: То есть, 3 файла:
li Имя1 /li li Имя2 /li li Имя 3 /li

Comment: Так сейчас просто выводиться Имя1, Имя2, Имя3. Они не меняются же. А нужно вывести имена загруженных файлов. Они другие же. Те файлы которые попадают в inpit file

Comment: @w3cwhy Вы определитесь что Вы хотите и отредактируйте свой вопрос в соответствии с этим. В вопросе указано что у Вас проблема с запятой (решена), а в комментариях Вы прояснили что нужно еще обернуть название в тег li (решено). Теперь ***примените*** мой пример в своем коде. Здесь приведена иллюстрация того как это сделать, относительно Вашего кода где отсутствует логика попадания названий в массив

Answer (score -1):

```js
input.onchange = function() {
    files.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = this.files[i].name;
        files.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input" multiple>
<ul id="files"></ul>
```